# Validation against JSON Schema sends an additional validation message

Tags: json, jsonschema

I need to validate json

```
[
{
    "relatedParty": "tr13",
    "action": "b"
},
{
    "relatedParty": "er127"
}
```

]

I would like to validate stricture and properties values. So I've written the following json schema:

```
{
"type": "array",
"maxItems": 4,
"items": {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "relatedParty": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "tr\\d{2}"
                },
                "action": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "a"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "relatedParty": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "pattern": "er\\d{3}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

But if I have wrong value in *action* I get validation message for both *relatedParty* and *action* properties.

[image]

Could anyone one explain why I got 2 validation messages rather then one and how it possible to adjust my validation schema to get only 1 message?

**UPDATES:**

Tried to validate the same json-object with the following json-schema:

```
{
"type": "array",
"maxItems": 4,
"items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "relatedParty": {
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "pattern": "tr\\d{2}"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "er\\d{3}"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "$defs": {
        "tr-requires-action": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "relatedParty": {
                        "pattern": "tr\\d{2}"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "relatedParty"
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "action": {
                        "pattern": "a"
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "action"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I've got 'No errors found. JSON validates against the schema' message. But the difference in  'action' property is still there.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `oneOf` keyword means one and only one of the schemas must validate successfully. The JSON Schema validator finds that both schemas fail and tells you the errors in both. Although it's obvious to a human looking at the schema that it's switching off of the value of the "relatedParty" property, the validator can't intuit your intention.

You can make your intention explicit to the validator using the `if`/`then` keywords.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "relatedParty": {
      "type": "string",
      "oneOf": [
        { "pattern": "tr\\d{2}" },
        { "pattern": "er\\d{3}" }
      ]
    }
  },

  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/$defs/tr-requires-action" }
  ],

  "$defs": {
    "tr-requires-action": {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "relatedParty": { "pattern": "tr\\d{2}" }
        },
        "required": ["relatedParty"]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "action": { "pattern": "a" }
        },
        "required": ["action"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(I had to make some assumptions about your data model, but hopefully you get the idea and can adapt the example.)

Comment: Jason Desrosiers, thank you for your answer. I've tried to adapt your draft and now I get 'No errors found. JSON validates against the schema' message. Good message but my json still has 1 mismatch and I need 1 message about it.

Comment: I'd be happy to help you work through the additional issues, but I can't do much without being able to see the schema you are using.

Comment: I added to the ticket description a json schema that I use to get 'No error found' message. For this result I tried to use the scheme  you kindly provided with if-then condition but remove allOf="$ref": "#/$defs/tr-requires-action"  property since it caused 'Could not resolve schema reference '#/$defs/tr-requires-action' error message. I would appreciate if you could help me to correct the schema to get a validation message only about  the difference in 'action' property.

Comment: If you remove the `allOf`, the `if`/`then` will never be applied. That's why you aren't getting any errors. The reason your `$ref` isn't working is because `$defs` is in the wrong place. It needs to be at the root of the schema. Move it up to the top level and it will work.